# Efficient way of assigning user IDs based in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to assign user IDs based on emails and my data looks like this:

```
email, date, status
user1@email.com, 28-05-2020, 1
user2@email.com, 28-05-2020, 5
user3@email.com, 29-05-2020, 2
user4@email.com, 30-05-2020, 1
```

A single user email can occur multiple times in the dataframe and I of course want to replace the email with a single user ID everytime. My current approach is:

```
users = all_data['email']
unique = all_data['email'].unique()
ids = [np.where(unique == user) for user in users]
```

Which works fine but takes forever to run for a large amount of data. For 50 records it runs in a breeze. For 500k records I have not seen it completing. Is there a way I can do this more efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, [`Series.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.factorize.html)

```
df['id'] = df['email'].factorize()[0]
```